# smtp email forwards with Gmail and Wordpress

Tags: email, smtp, wordpress, gmail

I'm looking for help. I'm trying to add a new email account to Gmail.  I've done it before for one of my websites email domain and it worked fine. However, now, this is the message I get. Furthermore, my marketing team member also could not have it set it up.

[image: error message snapshot 2]

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconfigured firewall which silently drops all SYN packets to port 587. Compare the output of a traceroute to port 80 with one to port 587:

```
# traceroute -n -T -p 587 -q 1 -f 14 -m 20 192.0.78.24
traceroute to 192.0.78.24 (192.0.78.24), 20 hops max, 60 byte packets
14  213.155.133.22  30.492 ms
15  80.91.249.88  25.303 ms
16  62.115.116.160  30.121 ms
17  *
18  *
19  *
20  *
```

```
# traceroute -n -T -p 80 -q 1 -f 14 -m 20 192.0.78.24
traceroute to 192.0.78.24 (192.0.78.24), 20 hops max, 60 byte packets
14  62.115.112.55  29.235 ms
15  213.155.134.117  29.376 ms
16  62.115.116.158  34.012 ms
17  62.115.46.38  33.967 ms
18  192.0.78.24  33.546 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick dns check of the domain ibpeditingservices.com reveals the following:

- The mx record points to `smtp-fwd.wordpress.com` and not `smtp.ibpeditingservices.com`. There is no such host as smtp.ibpeditingservices.com. Therefore it's no wonder that you can not connect to it. Try with the other address and see if it works. Or contact the administrator responsible for ibpeditingservices.com domain.

Here is the host command output:

```
root@server#host smtp.ibpeditingservices.com
smtp.ibpeditingservices.com is an alias for ibpeditingservices.com.
ibpeditingservices.com has address 192.0.78.24
ibpeditingservices.com has address 192.0.78.25
ibpeditingservices.com mail is handled by 10 smtp-fwd.wordpress.com.


root@server#host smtp-fwd.wordpress.com
smtp-fwd.wordpress.com has address 192.0.97.133
```

You can check it yourself here: http://mxtoolbox.com/